# How to import tesseract in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, tesseract

Trying to extract text from image using tesseract python.Have installed tesseract....

```
tesseract 4.1.0-rc1-21-g8e83  
leptonica-1.77.0   
libjpeg 6b : libpng 1.2.54 : zlib 1.2.8  
Found AVX2  
Found AVX  
Found SSE
```

But getting the below error when trying to import tesseract in python file

> import tesseract
>
> ImportError: No module named 'tesseract'

Comment: the `tesseract` package you installed seems like a binary rather than a python module. How did you install it?

Comment: tried different ways....
sudo apt-get install tesseract      
sudo apt-get install pytesseract

Comment: ok, `apt-get install tesseract` will put the `tesseract` binary into `/usr/local/bin`, which is *not* importable by Python. If you do `pip freeze | grep tesseract` are you able to see it installed?

Comment: and just for clarity, are you running this in a python virtual environment?

Comment: pip freeze | grep tesseract    gave me...
pytesseract==0.2.6
tesseract==0.1.3
tesseract-ocr==0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

- Have you installed tesseract?
- Have you installed pytesseract?
- What code are you running?

Here's a tutorial on how to set up using pytesseract to use tesseract with python:
https://www.linux.com/blog/using-tesseract-ubuntu

Comment: tesseract img.png out is working well...i.e., from command line..... But coming to the python script, the error is as follows : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pytesseract import image_to_string 
ImportError: No module named 'pytesseract'

Comment: yeah...installed tesseract, pytesseract

Comment: Actually trying to run the code from below link....
https://github.com/artunit/ossocr

python ossocr.py -c True -l eng -f page.jpg

Comment: If tesseract is installed correctly but python can't find the module, it sounds like you didn't install the pytesseract package correctly. It shouldn't be `sudo apt-get install pytesseract` like you state in a comment on the question but `sudo pip install pytesseract`.

Comment: Done that also.....
Requirement already satisfied: pytesseract in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pytesseract) (3.1.2)